# Parsing e-mail, only reply, when returned from Mandrill Inbound API

Tags: php, json, email, mandrill

Using Mandrill's API and their Inbound routing abilities, I'm trying to receive *only* the reply from the e-mail.  I'm trying to parse just the latest response, similar to how Asana or Zendesk allow you to reply to an e-mail and it will end up in their database (rather than using their webapps).

This is the JSON payload that Mandrill returns:

```
[
    {
        "event": "inbound",
        "ts": 1421946625,
        "msg": {
            "raw_msg": "Received: from server (unknown [ip])\n\tby ip-ip (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 0F62820519\n\tfor <from@mail.mydomain.com>; Thu, 22 Jan 2015 17:10:24 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: from server ([ip]) by\n server ([ip]) with mapi id\n ip; Thu, 22 Jan 2015 09:10:23 -0800\nFrom: person<person@mydomain.com>\nTo: Person\n\t<person@mail.mydomain.com>\nSubject: test\nThread-Topic: test\nThread-Index: AQHQNmZOwbsfpy7UQUuXQM6h0Jn9Gw==\nDate: Thu, 22 Jan 2015 17:10:22 +0000\nMessage-ID: <message@mydomain.com>\nReferences: <id@api.mydomain.com>\nIn-Reply-To: <id@api.mydomain.com>\nAccept-Language: en-US\nContent-Language: en-US\nX-MS-Has-Attach:\nX-MS-TNEF-Correlator:\nx-originating-ip: [myip]\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"us-ascii\"\nContent-ID: <id@mydomain.com>\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n\ntest",
            "headers": {
                "Received": [
                    "from server (unknown [ip]) by ip (Postfix) with ESMTPS id id for <person@mail.mydomain.com>; Thu, 22 Jan 2015 17:10:24 +0000 (UTC)",
                    "from server ([ip]) by server ([ip]) with mapi id id; Thu, 22 Jan 2015 09:10:23 -0800"
                ],
                "From": "Person Person <person@mydomain.com>",
                "To": "Person Person <person@mail.mydomain.com>",
                "Subject": "test",
                "Thread-Topic": "test",
                "Thread-Index": "id==",
                "Date": "Thu, 22 Jan 2015 17:10:22 +0000",
                "Message-Id": "<id@mydomain.com>",
                "References": "<id@api.mydomain.com>",
                "In-Reply-To": "<id@api.mydomain.com>",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US",
                "Content-Language": "en-US",
                "X-Ms-Has-Attach": "",
                "X-Ms-Tnef-Correlator": "",
                "X-Originating-Ip": "[ip]",
                "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=\"us-ascii\"",
                "Content-Id": "<id@server>",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "quoted-printable",
                "Mime-Version": "1.0"
            },
            "text": "test",
            "text_flowed": false,
            "from_email": "person@mydomain.com",
            "from_name": "Person Person",
            "to": [
                [
                    "person@mail.mydomain.com",
                    "Person Person"
                ]
            ],
            "subject": "test",
            "spf": {
                "result": "permerror",
                "detail": "SPF Permanent Error: No valid SPF record for included domain: _spf.intermedia.net: include:_spf.intermedia.net"
            },
            "spam_report": {
                "score": 0.6,
                "matched_rules": [
                    {
                        "name": "RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW",
                        "score": -0.7,
                        "description": "RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": null,
                        "score": 0,
                        "description": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "listed",
                        "score": 0,
                        "description": "in list.dnswl.org]"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "RDNS_NONE",
                        "score": 1.3,
                        "description": "Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dkim": {
                "signed": false,
                "valid": false
            },
            "email": "person@mail.mydomain.com",
            "tags": [],
            "sender": null,
            "template": null
        }
    }
]
```

The problem is that in the `text` key in the schema returns the ENTIRE e-mail chain when I just need the reply.  I've tried adding an underscore to the top of my e-mail template, and when I receive the JSON payload  POSTed to my server, I get only everything above the underscore.  However, mail clients (I'm using Mac's Mail client) add on dates, froms, tos, etc.

How am I able to parse this so I can receive JUST the reply and any signature with it and not the unnecessary text that's included?

Here's the snippet that's working that gets rid of the e-mail chain that comes below:

```
$response = substr($request['msg']['text'], 0, strpos($input['msg']['text'], '_'));
```

The line above gets the string from the beginning up until it hits the `_` in the e-mail template.  The e-mail client adds above my template when someone replies (rendering the underscore only useful for ridding the e-mail chain that comes with the response, and not what's tacked on above), and that's the bit I need to remove so that I get ONLY the reply.

Visually, this is what the client does:

[image]

As you can see it adds on `On Jan 22...` which is what I'm trying to eliminate when parsing it when the Mandrill API sends it to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searched around a bit more and found this repo:

https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser

This repository has a method in its API `getContent()` that returns only the e-mail reply.

This did the trick.